# SVG Glow Effect in CSS / JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a question regarding SVG Glow effect. I would like to set glow to group "suteki_201_" similar to the RED effect in this link: https://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc (I would like his eyes to neon glow - blink animation in different color) i tried using different styles but no success... could you please help?

My code for SVG image is:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Marko" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .dane0{fill:#D3D3D3;}
 .dane1{fill:#B0B0B0;}
 .dane2{fill:#303347;}
 .dane3{opacity:0.54;fill:#4A4D67;}
 .dane4{opacity:0.54;fill:#5F6380;}
 .dane5{opacity:0.37;fill:#010101;}
 .dane6{opacity:0.67;fill:#4A4D67;}
 .dane7{fill:#010101;}
 .dane8{opacity:0.72;}
 .dane9{fill:#77CFE2;}
 .dane10{fill:#9BD9E2;}
 .dane11{fill:#FBF5A9;}
 .dane12{fill:#C6C473;}
 .dane13{fill:#A3A061;}
 .dane14{opacity:0.67;}
 .dane15{fill:#242733;}
 .dane16{opacity:0.25;fill:#17191F;}
</style>
<g id="suteki_202_">
 <path id="suteki_73_" class="dane0" d="M176.5,174.3c-2.7-0.1-3.3,4.8-3.3,4.8c4,9.4,12.2,16.7,12.2,16.7c-3.9-15.1-1.6-17.3-1.6-17.3
  S179.2,174.4,176.5,174.3z"/>
 <path id="suteki_72_" class="dane1" d="M175.8,179.7c2.4,5.7,6.4,10.7,9.2,13.6c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.5,0.6,2.3c0,0-8.2-7.3-12.2-16.7
  c0,0,0.6-4.8,3.3-4.8c0.7,0,1.6,0.3,2.4,0.8C176.4,174.9,175.8,179.7,175.8,179.7z"/>
 <g id="suteki_283_">
  <path id="suteki_71_" class="dane2" d="M184.3,207.6c0,0-27.3-29.9-16.4-28.8c55.5,7.9,104.7,50.7,104.7,50.7s21.9,18.8,25.8,65.7
   c0,0-13.3,38.9-54.7,46.1c0,0-23.2-3.4-37-16.4c0,0,13.9,19.5,44.4,37.1c0,0,15.2,5.9,56.7-30.5l2.3-16.8c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6
   c0,0,35.4,8.4,66.1-6.2c31.9-15.2,36.7-29.2,23-65.6c-44.6-27.2-121.9-61.5-121.9-61.5c-71.9-16.4-184.5-11.7-184.5-11.7
   S129.6,184.2,184.3,207.6z"/>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_70_" class="dane3" d="M350.8,226.7c0,0-6.3,11.2-16.2,8.6c-9.9-2.6-30.8-30.7-30.8-30.7s22.2,21.6,31.5,23.7
  C344.5,230.6,350.8,226.7,350.8,226.7z"/>
 <path id="suteki_69_" class="dane4" d="M340,239.8c0,0-6.9,8.6-22.1-1.7c-11.1-7.5-13.5-22.3-27-43.2c17.3,18.7,20.4,30.1,30.6,37.1
  C335.4,241.6,340,239.8,340,239.8z"/>
 <path id="suteki_68_" class="dane5" d="M362.1,227.6C349.9,239,326,252.3,326,252.3s2.7,16-0.5,22c-3.3,6-8.5,3.1-8.5,3.1
  s-4.9-25.6-32.8-54.7c-86-75.6-118-43.7-118-43.7c55.1,4.4,106.6,50.4,106.6,50.4s21.9,18.8,25.8,65.7c0,0-13.3,38.9-54.7,46.1
  c0,0-23.2-3.4-37-16.4c0,0,13.9,19.5,44.4,37.1c0,0,15.2,5.9,56.7-30.5l2.3-16.8c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6c0,0,32.8,7,64.1-6.3
  c0,0,6.3-2.3,19.2-10.5C411.1,257.1,362.1,227.6,362.1,227.6z"/>
 <path id="suteki_67_" class="dane6" d="M165.3,162.3c54.2-4.7,122.7,27.2,122.7,27.2l62.5,11.8c0,0,1.1,10.7,5.7,22.4l74.1,49.6
  c14.3-10.9,15.8-26.6,5.7-55c0,0-29.6-20-121.9-61.5c-68.6-16.3-184.5-11.7-184.5-11.7s0,39.1,54.7,62.5
  C184.3,207.6,135.6,168.3,165.3,162.3z"/>
 <path id="suteki_66_" class="dane7" d="M356.2,223.7l-22.2,0.2l-46-34.4l10.2,1.9c0,0-0.4-1.7,2.6-5c0,0-1.6,3.9-0.1,5.4l5,0.9
  c0,0-0.3-5.1,3.3-6.8c0,0-2.8,3.1-0.2,7.4l41.8,7.7L356.2,223.7z"/>
 <g id="suteki_201_">
  <g id="suteki_276_" class="dane8">
   <path id="suteki_65_" class="dane9" d="M330,211.5c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10c0-0.9-0.2-1.7-0.4-2.6l-17.7-3.2c-1.2,1.7-1.9,3.6-1.9,5.8
    C320,207,324.5,211.5,330,211.5z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="suteki_274_" class="dane8">
   <path id="suteki_64_" class="dane9" d="M329,207.9c3.5,0,6.3-2.8,6.3-6.3c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6l-11.2-2.1c-0.8,1-1.2,2.3-1.2,3.7
    C322.6,205.1,325.5,207.9,329,207.9z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="suteki_272_" class="dane8">
   <path id="suteki_63_" class="dane10" d="M334,204.7c2,0,3.6-1.6,3.6-3.6c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.9l-6.4-1.2c-0.4,0.6-0.7,1.3-0.7,2.1
    C330.4,203.1,332,204.7,334,204.7z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_62_" class="dane0" d="M190.3,174c-3.9-0.1-4.8,6.9-4.8,6.9c5.8,13.6,17.7,24.2,17.7,24.2
  c-5.6-21.8-2.4-25.1-2.4-25.1S194.2,174.1,190.3,174z"/>
 <path id="suteki_61_" class="dane1" d="M189.3,181.8c3.5,8.3,9.3,15.4,13.3,19.8c0.2,1.1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.3c0,0-11.9-10.6-17.7-24.2
  c0,0,0.8-7,4.8-6.9c1,0,2.3,0.5,3.5,1.1C190.1,174.9,189.3,181.8,189.3,181.8z"/>
 <path id="suteki_60_" class="dane11" d="M434.8,269.4c0,0-53.7-41.9-72.8-50.3c0,0-1.9-16-5.8-24c0,0-11.9-12.2-69.2-10.5
  c0,0-82.3-34-131.3-23.3l3.3-2c51.3-8.3,128.8,21.7,128.8,21.7c37.1-2.1,72.2,8.4,72.2,8.4c5.2,8.8,7.2,26.4,7.2,26.4
  c25.4,12.8,71,49.8,71,49.8S436.7,267.6,434.8,269.4z"/>
 <g id="suteki_266_">
  <path id="suteki_59_" class="dane12" d="M364.8,217c0,0-1.2-17-6.4-25.8c0,0-29-11.4-71-8.1c0,0-46.3-16.9-87.3-23l-2.5,1.1
   c41,5.9,89.4,23.5,89.4,23.5c57.3-1.8,69.2,10.5,69.2,10.5c3.9,7.9,5.8,24,5.8,24c19.1,8.5,72.8,50.3,72.8,50.3
   c2-2.1,3.4-3.8,3.4-3.8S390.2,229.7,364.8,217z"/>
  <path id="suteki_58_" class="dane13" d="M157.2,160.5l-1.5,0.9c14.5-2.6,25.6-2.6,41.9-0.2l2.5-1.1
   C184.2,157.7,168.1,158,157.2,160.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="suteki_263_" class="dane14">
  <path id="suteki_57_" class="dane15" d="M363.9,217.8c0,0-1.2-17-6.4-25.8c0,0-29-11.4-71-8.1c0,0-46.3-16.9-87.3-23l-2.5,1.1
   c41,5.9,89.4,23.5,89.4,23.5c57.3-1.8,69.2,10.5,69.2,10.5c3.9,7.9,5.8,24,5.8,24c19.1,8.5,72.8,50.3,72.8,50.3
   c1.9-1.4,3.7-3.6,3.7-3.6S389.3,230.5,363.9,217.8z"/>
  <path id="suteki_56_" class="dane15" d="M155.7,161.4l-1.4,0.7c15-2.2,26.1-2.5,42.3-0.2l2.5-1.1
   C183.3,158.5,166.6,158.9,155.7,161.4z"/>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_55_" class="dane16" d="M436.2,218.6c11.6,39.4-17.1,70.5-93,56.6c-43.3,21-56.6,74.4-56.6,74.4l21.7-17.1l1.9-17.8
  c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6c0,0,33.3,7.7,64.6-5.6C417.2,280.4,460.8,270.4,436.2,218.6z"/>
 <path id="suteki_54_" class="dane5" d="M350.6,201c-2.8-0.5-62.6-11.5-62.6-11.5c-37.3-15.4-69.2-25-99.9-27.2
  c-55.8-5.4-27.8,23.7-5.3,44.3l1.5,1c0,0-54.7-46.5-7.6-44.2c55-0.5,111.3,29.1,111.3,29.1l58.9,11.7c0,0,2.6,7,3.6,19.4l75.7,52.2
  c1.8-1.2,2.7-1.7,4.2-2.7l-74.1-49.6C353.2,211.6,350.6,201,350.6,201z"/>
 <path id="suteki_53_" class="dane7" d="M430.9,273.3c0,0-23.3,22.1-72.6,18.3c0,0,51.7-6.3,62.4-24.7L430.9,273.3z"/>
 <g id="suteki_252_">
  <path id="suteki_51_" class="dane0" d="M270.2,365.1c-2.5,1.2-4.9-3-4.9-3c-0.1-10.2,4.5-20.2,4.5-20.2c2.5,15.4,5.4,16.5,5.4,16.5
   S272.7,363.9,270.2,365.1z"/>
  <path id="suteki_50_" class="dane0" d="M308.3,339.8c-2.6,3.1-8.6-1-8.6-1c-6.5-13.8-6.5-30.2-6.5-30.2c13,19.3,17.7,19,17.7,19
   S310.9,336.7,308.3,339.8z"/>
  <path id="suteki_49_" class="dane0" d="M291.4,358.6c-2.9,2.8-8.4-1.9-8.4-1.9c-5-14.4-3.3-30.7-3.3-30.7
   c11,20.5,15.6,20.8,15.6,20.8S294.3,355.7,291.4,358.6z"/>
  <path id="suteki_48_" class="dane1" d="M301.9,335.5c-3.9-8.2-5.4-17.4-6.1-23.5c-0.8-1.1-1.6-2.2-2.4-3.4c0,0,0,16.4,6.5,30.2
   c0,0,6,4.2,8.6,1c0.6-0.7,1-1.7,1.4-2.9C307.1,339.1,301.9,335.5,301.9,335.5z"/>
  <path id="suteki_47_" class="dane1" d="M267.4,360.5c-0.1-6.2,1.6-12.3,3-16.2c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.4-2.3c0,0-4.6,10-4.5,20.2
   c0,0,2.5,4.2,4.9,3c0.7-0.3,1.3-0.9,1.9-1.7C269.9,364.6,267.4,360.5,267.4,360.5z"/>
  <path id="suteki_46_" class="dane1" d="M284.9,353.3c-3.1-8.8-3.6-18.3-3.6-24.3c-0.5-1-1.1-2-1.7-3.1c0,0-1.7,16.3,3.3,30.7
   c0,0,5.5,4.8,8.4,1.9c0.8-0.8,1.4-2,1.9-3.3C290.4,358,284.9,353.3,284.9,353.3z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Check my answer, is that what u wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, Its not perfect, but you can play with the colors,opacity and timings.

To get the blur efects, I added Gaussian blur to svg

More info on Gauusian Blur effect here [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur)

```
<defs>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
```

Then, to apply the blur to any `path` / `g` add `filter="url(#f1)"`.
**Notice the id: ( f1 )**

I had to apply the filter to `suteki_65_` to make the outer circle glow and also had to duplicate the circle in order to retain the shape of the eye, as the filter effect blurs the shape.

And finally I applied CSS animation, to `suteki_65_` in order to make it blink
by changing the opacity.

```css
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    fill:red;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    fill:pink;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    fill:orange;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    fill:blue;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    fill:yellow;
  }
}

#suteki_65_ {
  animation: blink 1500ms infinite;
}

#suteki_65a_ {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Marko" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<style type="text/css">
 .dane0{fill:#D3D3D3;}
 .dane1{fill:#B0B0B0;}
 .dane2{fill:#303347;}
 .dane3{opacity:0.54;fill:#4A4D67;}
 .dane4{opacity:0.54;fill:#5F6380;}
 .dane5{opacity:0.37;fill:#010101;}
 .dane6{opacity:0.67;fill:#4A4D67;}
 .dane7{fill:#010101;}
 .dane8{opacity:0.72;}
 .dane9{fill:#77CFE2;}
 .dane10{fill:#9BD9E2;}
 .dane11{fill:#FBF5A9;}
 .dane12{fill:#C6C473;}
 .dane13{fill:#A3A061;}
 .dane14{opacity:0.67;}
 .dane15{fill:#242733;}
 .dane16{opacity:0.25;fill:#17191F;}
</style>
<g id="suteki_202_">
 <path id="suteki_73_" class="dane0" d="M176.5,174.3c-2.7-0.1-3.3,4.8-3.3,4.8c4,9.4,12.2,16.7,12.2,16.7c-3.9-15.1-1.6-17.3-1.6-17.3
  S179.2,174.4,176.5,174.3z"/>
 <path id="suteki_72_" class="dane1" d="M175.8,179.7c2.4,5.7,6.4,10.7,9.2,13.6c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.5,0.6,2.3c0,0-8.2-7.3-12.2-16.7
  c0,0,0.6-4.8,3.3-4.8c0.7,0,1.6,0.3,2.4,0.8C176.4,174.9,175.8,179.7,175.8,179.7z"/>
 <g id="suteki_283_">
  <path id="suteki_71_" class="dane2" d="M184.3,207.6c0,0-27.3-29.9-16.4-28.8c55.5,7.9,104.7,50.7,104.7,50.7s21.9,18.8,25.8,65.7
   c0,0-13.3,38.9-54.7,46.1c0,0-23.2-3.4-37-16.4c0,0,13.9,19.5,44.4,37.1c0,0,15.2,5.9,56.7-30.5l2.3-16.8c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6
   c0,0,35.4,8.4,66.1-6.2c31.9-15.2,36.7-29.2,23-65.6c-44.6-27.2-121.9-61.5-121.9-61.5c-71.9-16.4-184.5-11.7-184.5-11.7
   S129.6,184.2,184.3,207.6z"/>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_70_" class="dane3" d="M350.8,226.7c0,0-6.3,11.2-16.2,8.6c-9.9-2.6-30.8-30.7-30.8-30.7s22.2,21.6,31.5,23.7
  C344.5,230.6,350.8,226.7,350.8,226.7z"/>
 <path id="suteki_69_" class="dane4" d="M340,239.8c0,0-6.9,8.6-22.1-1.7c-11.1-7.5-13.5-22.3-27-43.2c17.3,18.7,20.4,30.1,30.6,37.1
  C335.4,241.6,340,239.8,340,239.8z"/>
 <path id="suteki_68_" class="dane5" d="M362.1,227.6C349.9,239,326,252.3,326,252.3s2.7,16-0.5,22c-3.3,6-8.5,3.1-8.5,3.1
  s-4.9-25.6-32.8-54.7c-86-75.6-118-43.7-118-43.7c55.1,4.4,106.6,50.4,106.6,50.4s21.9,18.8,25.8,65.7c0,0-13.3,38.9-54.7,46.1
  c0,0-23.2-3.4-37-16.4c0,0,13.9,19.5,44.4,37.1c0,0,15.2,5.9,56.7-30.5l2.3-16.8c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6c0,0,32.8,7,64.1-6.3
  c0,0,6.3-2.3,19.2-10.5C411.1,257.1,362.1,227.6,362.1,227.6z"/>
 <path id="suteki_67_" class="dane6" d="M165.3,162.3c54.2-4.7,122.7,27.2,122.7,27.2l62.5,11.8c0,0,1.1,10.7,5.7,22.4l74.1,49.6
  c14.3-10.9,15.8-26.6,5.7-55c0,0-29.6-20-121.9-61.5c-68.6-16.3-184.5-11.7-184.5-11.7s0,39.1,54.7,62.5
  C184.3,207.6,135.6,168.3,165.3,162.3z"/>
 <path id="suteki_66_" class="dane7" d="M356.2,223.7l-22.2,0.2l-46-34.4l10.2,1.9c0,0-0.4-1.7,2.6-5c0,0-1.6,3.9-0.1,5.4l5,0.9
  c0,0-0.3-5.1,3.3-6.8c0,0-2.8,3.1-0.2,7.4l41.8,7.7L356.2,223.7z"/>
 <g id="suteki_201_" >
  <g id="suteki_276_" class="dane8">
     <path id="suteki_65a_"  class="dane9" d="M330,211.5c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10c0-0.9-0.2-1.7-0.4-2.6l-17.7-3.2c-1.2,1.7-1.9,3.6-1.9,5.8
    C320,207,324.5,211.5,330,211.5z"/>
   <path id="suteki_65_"  filter="url(#f1)" class="dane9" d="M330,211.5c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10c0-0.9-0.2-1.7-0.4-2.6l-17.7-3.2c-1.2,1.7-1.9,3.6-1.9,5.8
    C320,207,324.5,211.5,330,211.5z"/>
        
      
  </g>
   
  <g id="suteki_274_" class="dane8">
   <path id="suteki_64_" class="dane9" d="M329,207.9c3.5,0,6.3-2.8,6.3-6.3c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6l-11.2-2.1c-0.8,1-1.2,2.3-1.2,3.7
    C322.6,205.1,325.5,207.9,329,207.9z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="suteki_272_" class="dane8">
   <path id="suteki_63_" class="dane10" d="M334,204.7c2,0,3.6-1.6,3.6-3.6c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.9l-6.4-1.2c-0.4,0.6-0.7,1.3-0.7,2.1
    C330.4,203.1,332,204.7,334,204.7z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_62_" class="dane0" d="M190.3,174c-3.9-0.1-4.8,6.9-4.8,6.9c5.8,13.6,17.7,24.2,17.7,24.2
  c-5.6-21.8-2.4-25.1-2.4-25.1S194.2,174.1,190.3,174z"/>
 <path id="suteki_61_" class="dane1" d="M189.3,181.8c3.5,8.3,9.3,15.4,13.3,19.8c0.2,1.1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.3c0,0-11.9-10.6-17.7-24.2
  c0,0,0.8-7,4.8-6.9c1,0,2.3,0.5,3.5,1.1C190.1,174.9,189.3,181.8,189.3,181.8z"/>
 <path id="suteki_60_" class="dane11" d="M434.8,269.4c0,0-53.7-41.9-72.8-50.3c0,0-1.9-16-5.8-24c0,0-11.9-12.2-69.2-10.5
  c0,0-82.3-34-131.3-23.3l3.3-2c51.3-8.3,128.8,21.7,128.8,21.7c37.1-2.1,72.2,8.4,72.2,8.4c5.2,8.8,7.2,26.4,7.2,26.4
  c25.4,12.8,71,49.8,71,49.8S436.7,267.6,434.8,269.4z"/>
 <g id="suteki_266_">
  <path id="suteki_59_" class="dane12" d="M364.8,217c0,0-1.2-17-6.4-25.8c0,0-29-11.4-71-8.1c0,0-46.3-16.9-87.3-23l-2.5,1.1
   c41,5.9,89.4,23.5,89.4,23.5c57.3-1.8,69.2,10.5,69.2,10.5c3.9,7.9,5.8,24,5.8,24c19.1,8.5,72.8,50.3,72.8,50.3
   c2-2.1,3.4-3.8,3.4-3.8S390.2,229.7,364.8,217z"/>
  <path id="suteki_58_" class="dane13" d="M157.2,160.5l-1.5,0.9c14.5-2.6,25.6-2.6,41.9-0.2l2.5-1.1
   C184.2,157.7,168.1,158,157.2,160.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="suteki_263_" class="dane14">
  <path id="suteki_57_" class="dane15" d="M363.9,217.8c0,0-1.2-17-6.4-25.8c0,0-29-11.4-71-8.1c0,0-46.3-16.9-87.3-23l-2.5,1.1
   c41,5.9,89.4,23.5,89.4,23.5c57.3-1.8,69.2,10.5,69.2,10.5c3.9,7.9,5.8,24,5.8,24c19.1,8.5,72.8,50.3,72.8,50.3
   c1.9-1.4,3.7-3.6,3.7-3.6S389.3,230.5,363.9,217.8z"/>
  <path id="suteki_56_" class="dane15" d="M155.7,161.4l-1.4,0.7c15-2.2,26.1-2.5,42.3-0.2l2.5-1.1
   C183.3,158.5,166.6,158.9,155.7,161.4z"/>
 </g>
 <path id="suteki_55_" class="dane16" d="M436.2,218.6c11.6,39.4-17.1,70.5-93,56.6c-43.3,21-56.6,74.4-56.6,74.4l21.7-17.1l1.9-17.8
  c0,0,7.4-15.6,36.7-24.6c0,0,33.3,7.7,64.6-5.6C417.2,280.4,460.8,270.4,436.2,218.6z"/>
 <path id="suteki_54_" class="dane5" d="M350.6,201c-2.8-0.5-62.6-11.5-62.6-11.5c-37.3-15.4-69.2-25-99.9-27.2
  c-55.8-5.4-27.8,23.7-5.3,44.3l1.5,1c0,0-54.7-46.5-7.6-44.2c55-0.5,111.3,29.1,111.3,29.1l58.9,11.7c0,0,2.6,7,3.6,19.4l75.7,52.2
  c1.8-1.2,2.7-1.7,4.2-2.7l-74.1-49.6C353.2,211.6,350.6,201,350.6,201z"/>
 <path id="suteki_53_" class="dane7" d="M430.9,273.3c0,0-23.3,22.1-72.6,18.3c0,0,51.7-6.3,62.4-24.7L430.9,273.3z"/>
 <g id="suteki_252_">
  <path id="suteki_51_" class="dane0" d="M270.2,365.1c-2.5,1.2-4.9-3-4.9-3c-0.1-10.2,4.5-20.2,4.5-20.2c2.5,15.4,5.4,16.5,5.4,16.5
   S272.7,363.9,270.2,365.1z"/>
  <path id="suteki_50_" class="dane0" d="M308.3,339.8c-2.6,3.1-8.6-1-8.6-1c-6.5-13.8-6.5-30.2-6.5-30.2c13,19.3,17.7,19,17.7,19
   S310.9,336.7,308.3,339.8z"/>
  <path id="suteki_49_" class="dane0" d="M291.4,358.6c-2.9,2.8-8.4-1.9-8.4-1.9c-5-14.4-3.3-30.7-3.3-30.7
   c11,20.5,15.6,20.8,15.6,20.8S294.3,355.7,291.4,358.6z"/>
  <path id="suteki_48_" class="dane1" d="M301.9,335.5c-3.9-8.2-5.4-17.4-6.1-23.5c-0.8-1.1-1.6-2.2-2.4-3.4c0,0,0,16.4,6.5,30.2
   c0,0,6,4.2,8.6,1c0.6-0.7,1-1.7,1.4-2.9C307.1,339.1,301.9,335.5,301.9,335.5z"/>
  <path id="suteki_47_" class="dane1" d="M267.4,360.5c-0.1-6.2,1.6-12.3,3-16.2c-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.4-2.3c0,0-4.6,10-4.5,20.2
   c0,0,2.5,4.2,4.9,3c0.7-0.3,1.3-0.9,1.9-1.7C269.9,364.6,267.4,360.5,267.4,360.5z"/>
  <path id="suteki_46_" class="dane1" d="M284.9,353.3c-3.1-8.8-3.6-18.3-3.6-24.3c-0.5-1-1.1-2-1.7-3.1c0,0-1.7,16.3,3.3,30.7
   c0,0,5.5,4.8,8.4,1.9c0.8-0.8,1.4-2,1.9-3.3C290.4,358,284.9,353.3,284.9,353.3z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```